# Haskell type of

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How can I find the type of a value in Haskell?

I want something like this:

```
data Vegetable = 
  Und Under
 |Abv Above

is_vegetable ::a->Bool  
is_vegetable a = if (a is of type Vegetable) then True else False
```

---

Update:

I want a datastructure to model the above tree.

I would also like to have some functions (is_drink, is_vegetable,is_wine,is_above) so that I can apply some filters on a list.
[image]

Comment: If you want to do this--particularly as a beginner--it probably means you're trying to solve your particular problem incorrectly. Of course, if you're just curious, it's fine, but you probably shouldn't need anything like this in your code.

Comment: I want a tree with multiple datatypes (Vegetables Drinks and under them Vegetables(Under, Above) and Drinks(Soda,Water,Wine) and I want to find if an element of type Soda is a Drink. Is there any better approach?

Comment: A better approach would be to put that all in one data type: `data Comestible = Under | Above | Soda ...`. Then you can write functions like `is_vegtable` by matching against the constructors of `Comestible`.

Comment: Never ever write `if cond then True else False`, just write `cond`.

Comment: I believe the question to ask is this: *Why* do you want the data types in that sort of tree? It's a very object-oriented thing to do, which doesn't necessarily translate well into functional programming.

Comment: @augustss, unless you are using [rebindable syntax](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) in GHC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do this in Haskell. All function arguments have concrete types (like `Int` and `String`) or they are [*type variables*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_variable) (like the `a` in your example). Type variables can be restricted to belong to a certain [*type class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class).

When you use an unrestricted type variable, then you cannot do anything interesting with the values of that type. By restricting the type variable to a type class, you get more power: if you have `Num a`, then you know that `a` is a numeric type and so you can add, multiple, etc.

From your comment, it sounds like you need a (bigger) data type to hold the different types of elements in your tree. The `Either a b` type may come in handy here. It is either `Left a` or `Right b` and so you can have a function like

```
is_vegetable :: Either Vegetable Drink -> Bool
is_vegetable (Left _) = True
is_vegetable (Right _) = False
```

Your tree nodes will then be `Either Vegetable Dring` elements.

Answer (score 15):

You don't. You rely on the type system to ensure that the value is a Vegetable --- if the value is not a Vegetable, your program won't compile, much less run.

```
is_vegetable :: Vegetable -> Bool
is_vegetable _ = True  -- so there is not much point to this function
```

Edit, upon seeing your comment:

```
data Foodstuff = Vegetable Vegetable
               | Drink Drink

is_vegetable :: Foodstuff -> Bool
is_vegetable (Vegetable _) = True
is_vegetable _             = False
```

But this is still probably not what you want. Instead you probably want something like

```
    case myFood of
         Vegetable vegetable -> -- something involving `vegetable`
         Drink drink         -> -- something involving `drink`
```

Answer (score 5):

Tip for reading function signatures in Haskell:

```
f :: a -> Bool
```

This means `f` takes one argument which could be *anything*, and `f` does not have any information about the type.  So it is impossible for `f` to know if the argument is a `Vegetable`.  There are only three possible definitions for `f` (two more for strict / non-strict variants, which I'm omitting for clarity):

```
-- version 1
f _ = True

-- version 2
f _ = False

-- version 3
f _ = undefined
```

You see `f` is a very boring function because it is not allowed to know anything about its parameter.  You could do something like this:

```
isVegetable :: Typeable a => a -> Bool
isVegetable x = case cast x :: Maybe Vegetable of
                  Just _ -> True
                  Nothing -> False
```

You would need to create an instance of `Typeable` for `Vegetable`,

```
data Vegetable = ... deriving Typeable
```

The signature `f :: Typeable a => a -> Bool` means that `f` has one parameter, and it does not know anything about that parameter except that the parameter has a type that is known at runtime.